# Get all `tr` tags in specific level in web browser c#

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

here is a sample html :

```
<form action="/opac-prod/search/briefListSearch.do" method="post" name="search_BrowseSearchHitsForm">
<table id="printTable" width="100%" align="center" dir="ltr">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-family:tahoma;font-size:11px">
                <table border="0" align="right" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        -- I want to get just this level tr tags , not in their children
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get all html elements which are tagged in `tr` but Not In All Levels. I mean that If I use a foreach loop to perform this, I can't actually do this. because I want to get All `tr` tags in **just** the last `tbody` tag (they have same code inside), not in their children too.
How can I perform this ?

I try this foreach loop but it goes on each `tr` tag that is there after `LoopElement` :

```
var htmlElement = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")[0].GetElementsByTagName("form")[0].GetElementsByTagName("table")["printTable"];
            if (htmlElement != null)
            {
                var elements = htmlElement.GetElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].GetElementsByTagName("tr")[0].GetElementsByTagName("td")[0].GetElementsByTagName("table")[0].GetElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
                foreach (HtmlElement element in elements.GetElementsByTagName("tr"))
                {
                    if (element.GetElementsByTagName("td")[0].GetElementsByTagName("table") != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var LoopElement =
                                element.GetElementsByTagName("td")[0].GetElementsByTagName("table")[0].GetElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].GetElementsByTagName("tr");
                            foreach (HtmlElement element1 in LoopElement)
                            {
                                 // This Loop 
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: C# does not run in the web browser, please be more specific.

Comment: @CharlieBrown ; I want all `tr` tags that come immediately after where I comment in html code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
tbody tr:first-of-type { 
    text-align: left; 
}
</style>
```

Use the above code to target first of type tr element of tbody.

However in your code you are using two tbody tags just give them different id say `first` and `second`.

Then you can target the `second` element like this:

```
<style> 
#second tr:first-of-type { 
    text-align: left; 
}
</style>
```

Comment: I can't make change on this site because it is not my own.